# C# data from database in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

I have a `ListBox` and some data in there from database. First row is a name (`string`) and the second row is price which is double. I would like to have word *Euros* behind the price but in database it should stay as double.

How should I do it?

[image: Listbox with data]

Code for my ListBox is:

```
<ListBox Name="BoozeList" Margin="10,124,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="233"
             Background="#FF79DCFA" BorderBrush="#FF0040FF">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UnitPrice}"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BoozesCollection" Source="{Binding Boozes}"/>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="JuicesCollection" Source="{Binding Juices}"/>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SnacksCollection" Source="{Binding Snacks}"/>

            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BoozesCollection}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource JuicesCollection}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource SnacksCollection}}"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StringFormat` on the unit price `TextBlock`.

If you want to display the euro sign next to the price:

```
<TextBlock Language="fr" Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat=C0}" />
```

Or if you want to display the text "Euros" (thanks to @Milan for pointing this out):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat={}{0} Euros }" />
```

Comment: more like "StringFormat={}{0:N} Euros", right? he wants the text "Euros" there